# Jenkins called job from pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using a plugin in Jenkins called Deploy to container. I created a Job called 'Deploy' to build this feature. How can I call this from pipeline that I created from another job?

I am using this code in the pipeline, but it doesn't trigger the Called to Deploy container and the configuration.

```
stage('Tomcat') {
    withMaven(maven: 'M2') {
        build job: 'Deploy'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, wrapping the `build` call inside `withMaven` is useless, as this will not affect the triggered *Deploy* job.

Assuming that you get an error message that a job called *Deploy* is not found, let me say that it searches for the job similar to like in directories:

- `build 'Deploy'` would trigger a job "next" to the current one.
- `build '/Deploy'` would trigger a job on the top level, no matter how deep inside folders (e.g. multi-branch projects or organisation folder projects) the current job is located.
- `build '../Deploy'` would trigger a job one level above, in case of a multi-branch project, this would be needed, if you have such non-folder-based job and trigger it from a multi-branch project (so you have to go one level up from the job inside the multi-branch project).

If this does not help, edit your post and add the URLs of the *Deploy* job and the one that should trigger it.